# elasticsearch group by ID field and perform max on date field

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

My index has data as mentioned below.

```
Id    version_number groupId   indexDate
1    v1                 1    2016-11-15T12:00:00
2    v1                 2    2016-11-20T12:00:00
3    v2                 2    2016-12-01T12:00:00
4    v1                 3    2016-13-01T12:00:00
5    v1                 4    2016-11-01T12:00:00
6    v2                 4    2016-13-01T12:00:00
7    v1                 5    2016-14-01T12:00:00
```

How can i write a elasticsearch query in java. If i search by date 2016-13-01T12:00:00 i expect to see the latest version per groupId which has indexDate less than or equal to the date searched?

output expected:

```
Id    version_number   groupId   indexDate
1    v1                  1       2016-13-01T12:00:00
2    v2                  2       2016-11-20T12:00:00
6    v3                  3       2016-10-01T12:00:00
7    v2                  4       2016-10-01T12:00:00
```

I dont see a max function on date field in elasticsearch to achieve this.

Comment: That's a weird date `2013-13-01T12:00:00`;-)

Comment: Two questions: Why don't we see `v4` in your expected output? Why are there two documents with id 6?

Comment: I have edited the question and answer. I missed v4 by mistake in the o/p.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first aggregate on `version_number`and then use a [`top_hits`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) sub-aggregation sorted on descending `indexDate` and returning the id of the first document of that bucket.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "by_version": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "version_number"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_date": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "indexDate": "desc"
            },
            "_source": [
              "id"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I kind of translated your query in java as below. But it is returning all the versions no matter what date i provide. can you please review the same.       **client.prepareSearch(versionIndexName).setTypes(versionIndexType).addAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("version").field("version").size(0)
                .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.topHits("top").setExplain(true)
                        .setSize(1)
                        .setFrom((size * index)).addSort("versionDate",SortOrder.DESC).setFetchSource(true))).execute().actionGet();**

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong. `size(0)` will return all versions