# ElasticSearch aggregation over aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch index with Orders. An Order can have a state (e.g. Created, Processing, Confirmed). I want to create a report that shows the number of orders per state, per month. So I want to see a report like:

```
| x     | Created | Processing | Confirmed |
|-------|---------|------------|-----------|
| March |      10 |         15 |         5 |
| April |       8 |          9 |        33 |
```

I figured I need to store something like a "Historic Order", because the same Order will be Created in March but Confirmed in April. So I store the Order together with its state and also the date it transitioned in that state.

I found [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36781397/elasticsearch-group-by-id-field-and-perform-max-on-date-field) which shows how to get the max state. But now I don't know how to aggregate on that aggregation and get the number of states per time period.

The query I have so far looks a bit like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "stateDate": {
        "lte": "2019-05-30"
      }
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "by_order_id": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "orderId"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_state": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "stateDate": "desc"
            },
            "_source": [
              "orderState",
              "stateDate"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Update: some example of the Order object:

```
{
    "orderId": "1234-5678-abcd", // some guid
    "orderState": "Created|Processing|Confirmed", // enum
    "stateDate": "2019-05-31 10:33" // the date-time when the order transitioned in that state
}
```

And imagine these records:

```
| orderId    | orderState | stateDate  |
|------------|------------|------------|
| 123        | Created    | 2019-05-30 |
| 123        | Processing | 2019-05-31 |
| 123        | Confirmed  | 2019-06-01 |
| 456        | Created    | 2019-06-01 |
| 456        | Processing | 2019-06-01 |
```

I want a report that says I had 1 order in Processing in May (order 123, that's its final status within May). In June it should say I had 1 Confirmed order (123) and 1 in Processing (456).

I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Can you post some sample data? Without seeing the structure of data, it is difficult to write any query.

Comment: {
    "aggs": {
        "overtime": {
            "date_histogram":{
                "field":"stateDate",
                "interval": "month"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "overstate":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"orderState"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
This will give you monthwise state based aggregation. You can convert internal terms aggregation to script aggregation to get unique orders by state.